# Does "delegate" mean a type or an object?

Tags: .net, delegates, msdn

Reading from MSDN:
"A delegate is a type that references a method. Once a delegate is assigned a method, it behaves exactly like that method."

**Does then "delegate" mean a type or an object?!**

...It cannot be both. It seems to me that the single word is used in two different meanings:

1. a type containing a reference to a method of some specified signature,
2. an object of that type, which can be actually called like a method.

I would prefer a more precise vocabulary and use "delegate type" for the first case. I have been recently reading a lot about events and delegates and that ambiguity was making me confused many times.

Some other uses of "delegate" word in MSDN in the first meaning:

- "Custom event delegates are needed only when an event generates event data"
- "A delegate declaration defines a class that is derived from the class System.Delegate"

Some other uses of "delegate" word in MSDN in the second meaning:

- "specify a delegate that will be called upon the occurrence of some event"
- "Delegates are objects that refer to methods. They are sometimes described as type-safe 
  function pointers"

What do you think? Why did people from Microsoft introduced this ambiguity? Am I the only person to have conceptual problems with different notions being referenced with the same word.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The text is using the word `delegate` both ways; as a type and as an instance of the type.

It should say "A delegate *type* is a type that references a method. Once a delegate *instance* is assigned a method, it behaves exactly like that method."

Comment: Note that the `delegate` keyword in C# is just as ambiguous: `delegate xyz Xyz()` indicates a delegate *type*, `delegate() { ... }` indicates a delegate *instance*.

Comment: @Ruben I'm late to the party, but isn't this ambiguity the case with every type name/constructor name pair?

Comment: @PeterSchneider, I think the real issue with the original text is the formulation _once a delegate is assigned a method_; that's a really weird way of saying _once you create a delegate (instance) from a method (reference)_. Using the word "assign", which is normally used in a different context (`x = y`, not `x = new X(y)`, ignoring C# here, which explicitly allows both syntaxes for delegates), in combination with the ambiguity of xyz type vs. xyz instance, makes the original text highly confusing for someone unfamiliar with the concept that it's trying to explain in the first place.

Comment: The `delegate` _keyword_ suddenly changes it's interpretation from a type declaration to an instantiation:  you'd have to know that `delegate { ... }` really means `new InferredDelegateType(generatedMethod)`; there are no such orthogonal uses for other keywords.

Comment: @Ruben Thanks for the thoughts, especially that `delegate  { ... }` actually defines an instance of an inferred (anonymous) type. I have to think about it -- my comment was purely formal, and I do not feel completely familiar with delegates in general (as opposed to feeling familiar with oldschool C function pointers). Part of this discomfort may indeed be based in terminology.

Answer (score 0):

A **delegate type** refers to a *signature*, not a *specific method*. A **delegate instance**, may, if assigned, contain one or more methods references.

So the delegate type is:

```
delegate void D();
```

The delegate instance is:

```
D d;
```

The delegate instance assignment may be:

```
d += new D (Method);
```